# Ansible Not copying directory using cp command

Tags: unix, centos, ansible

I have the following role:

```
---
- name: "Copying {{source_directory}} to {{destination_directory}}"
  shell: cp -r "{{source_directory}}" "{{destination_directory}}"
```

being used as follows:

```
- { role: copy_folder, source_directory: "{{working_directory}}/ipsc/dist", destination_directory: "/opt/apache-tomcat-base/webapps/ips" }
```

with the parameters: `working_directory: /opt/demoServer`

This is being executed after I remove the directory using this role (as I do not want the previous contents)

```
- name: "Removing Folder {{path_to_file}}"
  command: rm -r "{{path_to_file}}"
```

with parameters: `path_to_file: "/opt/apache-tomcat-base/webapps/ips"`

I get the following output:

```
TASK: [copy_folder | Copying /opt/demoServer/ipsc/dist to /opt/apache-tomcat-base/webapps/ips] *** 
<md1cat01-demo.lnx.ix.com> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: my.user
<md1cat01-demo.lnx.ix.com> REMOTE_MODULE command cp -r "/opt/demoServer/ipsc/dist" "/opt/apache-tomcat-base/webapps/ips" #USE_SHELL
...
changed: [md1cat01-demo.lnx.ix.com] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "cp -r \"/opt/demoServer/ipsc/dist\" \"/opt/apache-tomcat-base/webapps/ips\"", "delta": "0:00:00.211759", "end": "2016-02-05 11:05:37.459890", "rc": 0, "start": "2016-02-05 11:05:37.248131", "stderr": "", "stdout": "", "warnings": []}
```

What is happening is that there is never being a folder in that directory.
Basically the cp command is not doing it's job, but i get no error or so. If i run the copy command manually on the machine it works however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) module and set `directory_mode` to `yes`

Comment: copy copies from the local server to a remote server though no? I want to copy files on the same remote machine

Comment: If you use Ansible 2.0, then set `remote_src` to `yes`.